# Accessing SI Setup options

Tags: dm-script

I would like to write a script which can acquire an EELS spectrum image, followed by an EDX SI. Is there a way to access the Spectrum Image Setup to toggle the 'SI Signals' checkbox between EDS and EELS?

I am using DM 2.32, and when I use SIGetPaletteItemName() to look at what is available, DM returns all options for the clickable buttons on the SI panel except the Setup option.

Comment: Question needs improvement to explain the issue you, read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for more points

Comment: The question was sufficiently clear to people using DigitalMicropraph for which the [dm-script] tag stands.

Answer (score 0):

You can not access the setup options themselves by script. 
Unfortunately, I don't think you can change the to-be-acquired signal by script in GMS 2.x.

You can do this in GMS 3.x, but that is not much help to you, is it?
In GMS 3.x, the "to-be-acquired" signals are actually buttons on the UI and can therefore be toggled with the command using the button ID's 11-15.

Comment: Thank you, that answers my question exactly. It's good to know this has been implemented in GMS 3.x!